# What is the formula for text filtration and adding a word to another column?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

There are hospital names and medicine centers on my excel table on C column. I want to add word "hast" for the lines in which there are hospital names in the F column. What is the formula for this? I could do this by text filtration, yet I really wonder what the formula is for this. Thank you so much.

Best regards,
Seda

Comment: Do you mean that column F is not empty, or does it have to match column C?

Comment: Sorry, I wrote it wrong. F column is empty.

Comment: How do you determine those hospital names?  Are they in a different column that you can look for?  Or do they have hospital as suffix?  It is hard to know what you really want without any pic or data posted but the request you have shouldn't be too hard.

Answer (score 0):

So without data it's hard to determine, but I'm guessing that you either have hospital name or empty cell. In that case this would be the formula:

```
=IF(C1<>"",C1&"hast","")
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have xxx HASTANESİ or yyy SAĞLIK MERKEZİ in column C. If so, you could do it with this formula

=IFERROR(IF(SEARCH("HASTANE";C1);1;0);0)

you could also chekc my website, which is in Turkish, at http://www.excelinefendisi.com/Konular/Excel/FormulasMenusuFonksiyonlar_MetinselFonksiyonlar.aspx

Comment: Bir sürü formül söylediler denedim; bir tek sizinkinde uyarı vermedi; ama #AD? yazıyor bu sefer de. Ne yapabilirim?

Comment: Bu formül işe yaradı mı yaramadı mı, tam anlayamadım. Uyarı vermedi demişsiniz ama ne yapabilirim diye sorduğunuza göre tam ihityacınız bu değil sanırım. Bi de dosya desenini örnek bir satırla yazabilirmisiniz, orjnial sorunuzu edit yaparak